# Karate : Passing variable from one feature file to another as a query parameter

Tags: karate

I'm trying to execute a feature file and need which takes a query parameter from another feature.

Here is the feature files :
1. This file call two feature files. First feature file add a record in the database and returns json response. I have to use a property from the response and have to pass to another feature. Please find below for the features files.

Feature: 
  Background:

Scenario: 
Given call read('test_add.feature')

```
And def query1 = response.name

Given call read('test_get.feature') {'**query**' : #query1}
```

2. feature name - test_get.feature
   Feature: Add a new Nat bundle device

   Background:

   - url baseUrlWithContext
   - def headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

   Scenario: Addition

   Given headers headers

   And path '/test'

   And params **query**

   When method get

   Then status 200

Error :
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException:

cannot convert to map: **query**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `And params query`

Try this:

```
And param query = query
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20712574)

Comment: @PavelKovalev edited my answer. btw I am the author of Karate.

Comment: I'm very glad to e-meet you sir! I'm sorry for inconvenience. I edited/triaged/and sorted a few hundred posts, so short answers without comments usually a spam or low quality comments. Thank you for improving your answer!

Comment: @PavelKovalev wow. thank you ! wish all other mods were like you :)